# Craft Commerce: Export each order to a specific CSV file and send it throught email

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

Although I don't like this for some reasons, my client wants Craft Commerce to directly send specific formatted CSV file to their CRM system for each order.

Is it possible to write a Craft Commerce plugin to allow such a feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom [Craft plugin](http://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) (generate the boilerplate for it at https://pluginfactory.io) that listened to one of Craft Commerce's order events.  Likely [onSaveOrder](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onsaveorder) or [onOrderComplete](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onordercomplete) depending on your specific requirements.

From there, your plugin could build the CSV the old fashioned way in PHP, or use something like the [CSV library](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Once you've built the CSV, you can use Craft's [EmailService->sendEmail()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService#sendEmail-detail) (accessible through `craft()->email->sendEmail()` to add the attachment and shoot the email off.

Comment: I was really taken back to see that there is no built-in way to get orders out of craft commerce. It seems like a fairly big oversight. This platform seems unfinished to me.